# How can I extract the key.pem from the certificate in openssl?

Tags: openssl

I have the certificate and I want to extract the key that is inside.
I don't know if exist any command o how can I do.
Thanks you!

Comment: You can extract key and certificate file from the pfx by following the steps explained in http://www.markbrilman.nl/2011/08/howto-convert-a-pfx-to-a-seperate-key-crt-file/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command in openSSL to extract the publicKey.pem form Cert.pem is the following:

```
openssl x509 -noout -pubkey -in [cerFile.pem] -out [myPubKeyFile.pem]
```

and the answer was response in the next link:
[extract the public key from the certificate.pem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049115/extract-the-public-key-from-the-certificate-pem)