# extract the public key from the certificate.pem

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, public-key-encryption, public-key

I was trying to extract the public key with the certificate file that the partner give me in my public key file with the following command:

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in [certFile.pem]  > [myPubKeyFile.pem]
```

but it shows me the following error:

```
x509: Unknown parameter >
x509: Use -help for summary.
error in x509
```

How can I fix it?
thanks.

Comment: Works for me!  Are you sure you've typed it correctly?  If it still won't play, try `openssl x509 -noout -pubkey -in [cerFile.pem] -out [myPubKeyFile.pem]`

Comment: thanks you!
that command works!